# How to create an n*n grid of coordinates?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates

I am having trouble making a 8*8 grid of coordinates in Python 2.7

For the sake of demonstrating, I tried to make a 3x3 grid like this:

```
grid=[]

for col in xrange(3):
    grid.append([col])
    for row in xrange(3):
        grid[col].append([row])

print grid
```

I want to have:

```
grid = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

But what I got was:

```
grid = [[0, [0], [1], [2]], [1, [0], [1], [2]], [2, [0], [1], [2]]]
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a list comprehension, this will do it for you.

```
grid = [[row, col] for row in range(3) for col in range(3)]
```

Or, if you want to use for loops,

```
grid = []
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        grid.append([row, col])
```

Either of those give this value for `grid`:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a late answer, but another elegant solution is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

grid = list(itertools.product(xrange(3), xrange(3)))
```

*For Python 3 users, you can replace `xrange` by `range`.*

You get:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Here, coordinates are tuples. IMO, a non-mutable object makes more sense.